# Prevent delete when text is empty

Tags: c#

When a serial number that exists in the database is entered into the textbox it is successfully deleted with a message box. The problem is, even when the textbox is empty it still says it is successful.

```
try
    {
         connection.Open();

         OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
         command.Connection = connection;
         string deleteEntry = "delete from Inventory where SerialNumber='" + txtSerial.Text + "' ";           
         MessageBox.Show(deleteEntry);
         command.CommandText = deleteEntry;
         //TO READ DATA
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("Data Has Been Deleted");
         connection.Close(); // CLOSE HERE OR YOU CANNOT EDIT RECORDS SIMULTANEOUSLY
    }
         catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         connection.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: A delete that doesn't actually delete anything isn't going to throw an exception.  You can look at the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` to see how many rows were deleted though.

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want to avoid committing your delete statement if `txtSerial` is empty?

Comment: put a check at the top of your method if(string.IsNullOrEmpty( txtSerial.Text)){return;}  Then go read up on SQL injection attacks, and use a parameterized query.

Comment: Yes, if the text is empty I want to avoid the delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to avoid having your command execute if `txtSerial.Text` is null or empty, put in a check for it:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSerial.Text)) {
    try
        {
            connection.Open();
    (...)
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Provide a Serial")
}
```

Also, please look into [`parameterized queries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), and consider closing your connection in a `finally` block, or utilizing the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement for your connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (txtSerial.Text.Length != 0 ) 
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    } 
    Catch() ....... 
}
else
{     
      MessageBox.Show("Serial Number must be required...");
}
```

Trying this ...